# Puppeteere/Chromium pdf printing ignores css page-breaks in tables

Tags: printing, chromium, page-break

I was browsing the last hours to find a solution for my problem with latest puppeteer (2.0.0) / chromium 78.0.x to get our printing system working. We allow to setup page breaks in tables, which worked find in PhantomJS renderer, but not in the puppeteer/chromium solution.

Beside many little difference in global css and printing PDF header/footer the printing of tables was the last problem (hopefully).

It turns out that the "page-break-before: always" is simply ignored.

Example:

```
<table>
   <thead> ... </thead>
   <tbody> ... 
       <tr style="page-break-before: always;"> ...should be on next page ... </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Some of the Chrome forum articles point out, this has been solved.
So the question is what is causing the problem.

Regards,
Andre

PS) Later we found now: put a "display: block" on all tags of the table solves the problem. Maybe that helps someone. Any comments on that?

```
<table style="display: block;">
   <thead style="display: block;"> ... </thead>
   <tbody style="display: block;"> ... 
       <tr style="display: block; page-break-before: always;"> ...is now on the next page ... </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Trying a lot we noticed: put a "display: block" on the tags <table> <thead> <tbody> and <tr> solves the problem. Any more comments on that?

Answer (score 0):

Bad news for the solution we provided above. This destroys the feature of having table headers on each page.

setup 1)
Setting "display: block;" for the **thead** will disable the feature of having the table header on each page.

*==> no page break*

setup 2)
Set the **thead** to "display: table-header-group;" and tbody to "table-row-group" then the chrome will ignore the page-breaks.

*==> no table headers on each page*

setup 3) Having the thead: "display: table-header-group;" and the tbody: "display: block" is destroying the column structure. The body will be rendered only on the first column.

*==> Destroys the table. the body is just in the first column*

Here comes our hack to solve the problem. we use setup 3, with this:
- we build a table with just one column
- the column contains a table with all columns we really want to render
- the column widths are set to fix values (that was anyway the case in our rendering system)

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <td> <table> .... the header of the real table  </table> </td>
     </tr>
  </thead>


  <tbody style="display:block;">
     <tr>
        <td>
            <table> .... one row of the real table  </table>
        <td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>
            <table> .... another row of the real table  </table>
        <td>
     </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```